# What is an example of a Prettier rule that can't be done in EsLint?

Tags: eslint, prettier

I am curious, I see comments like this...

> As mentioned earlier, whereas Prettier takes care of your code formatting, ESLint takes care of your code style. The former does everything automatically for you. If you have set up Prettier, you can configure it to format your file on saving it. That way, you never need to worry about your code formatting anymore. Since Prettier is highly opinionated, you can do only minor configurations.
>
> The latter, ESLint, isn't intended to perform code style fixes automatically though. Instead, ESLint warns you about code smells

But clearly there is a lot of work being done by `intended` here for example eslint can handle plenty of stylistic stuff like [line length](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/max-len), [indent](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent), [new lines](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/linebreak-style), etc

In fact most of the stuff I see [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) has an eslint alternative. So why would I use prettier if I already use lint? What are the examples of prettier specific enforcement of styling?

Answer (score 2):

For some rules you mentioned, namely indent or new lines, it doesn't matter, both ESlint and prettier lead to the same result. However max-len and printWidth work significantly different. max-len will just count the number of characters and throws an error if it's exceeded, but the error needs to be manually fixed.

According to the [prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), here is how the printWidth option works in contrast:

> Prettier’s printWidth option does not work the same way. It is not the hard upper allowed line length limit. It is a way to say to Prettier roughly how long you’d like lines to be. Prettier will make both shorter and longer lines, but generally strive to meet the specified printWidth.

Additionally, prettier automatically fixes the line length of your lines. For example, see the following code:

```
function myVeryCoolFunctionWithLongName(myFirstFunctionArgument, mySecondFunctionArgument, myThirdFunctionArgument) {
}
```

With default prettier settings, it will be changed to:

```
function myVeryCoolFunctionWithLongName(
  myFirstFunctionArgument,
  mySecondFunctionArgument,
  myThirdFunctionArgument,
) {}
```

Whereas ESLint would just throw an error.

To summarize, while ESLint does a decent job in **detecting** formatting issues, prettier is much smarter in **fixing** your code to meet a consistent format. Read very closely again the sentence you cited:

> ESLint isn't intended to **perform code style fixes automatically**

Further reference:

- [ESLint froze stylistic rules](https://eslint.org/blog/2020/05/changes-to-rules-policies/) as of May 2020
- [TypeScript ESLint encourages using prettier for formatting](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/formatting/)

Comment: So this is as close to a good answer as I have seen. It does point out an added benefit in the sense of providing the additional formatting automagically. However, I think in the vein of feature I was looking for was something more like an actual feature and not just the way the feature is handled. For example in this case the eslint error would lead to me just formatting with IJ and checking back in. That being said I would like references for the 'ESLint isn't intended to perform code style fixes automatically' comment, because there are other formatting that eslint does handle Thank you!

Comment: @JGleason I understand that prettier alone is not a reputable source for you to prove the point that using linters is not the best solution for formatting. ESLint stopped development of stylistic rules as of May'20, see [this blog entry](https://eslint.org/blog/2020/05/changes-to-rules-policies). Also there is a widely used ESLint plugin for TypeScript, which encourages to use a tool like prettier over linters for formatting: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/formatting/.

Comment: A few weeks ago I was probably in a similar situation like you. I used ESLint for formatting and the WebStorm formatter. This approach has some downsides. You can only verify the formatting if there is a lint rule which checks it, that's not necessarily the case. You have a dependency to IntelliJ, there is a problem if someone is contributing who wants to use another IDE. This is why we are now moving to prettier. If you want I can add this to my answer, although this wasn't specifically asked for.

Comment: I'll give you the points but hold back the answer portion because I still don't really see this as being additional functionality. I also use raw ECMA script so I don't need to worry about the Typescript precompile stuff so maybe that is part of my situation. Perhaps it is a lot more crucial when using Typescript and I am just lacking that perspective.

Comment: Also missed this reference so I will look over it https://eslint.org/blog/2020/05/changes-to-rules-policies/

Answer (score 0):

As prettier docs mentioned:

> Linters have two categories of rules:
>
> Formatting rules: eg: max-len, no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs,
> keyword-spacing, comma-style…
>
> Prettier alleviates the need for this whole category of rules!
> Prettier is going to reprint the entire program from scratch in a
> consistent way, so it’s not possible for the programmer to make a
> mistake there anymore :)
>
> Code-quality rules: eg no-unused-vars, no-extra-bind,
> no-implicit-globals, prefer-promise-reject-errors…
>
> Prettier does nothing to help with those kind of rules. They are also
> the most important ones provided by linters as they are likely to
> catch real bugs with your code!
>
> In other words, use Prettier for formatting and linters for catching
> bugs!

In fact, prettier will do it faster and more predictable because it is designed to do so.
If you use ESLint for formatting, it would be like using a 5 pound hammer to drive a nail.

***Use the right tool for the right job***

I highly recommend you watch the [video of Theo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cd-gBxzcsdA) on this subject.

See more:

- [Josh Goldberg - Setting Up ESLint and TypeScript for React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSJBeWPIipQ)
- [Integrating with Linters](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html)

Comment: I will take a look at the links but I am looking for additional functionality not just performance.

Comment: What Functionallity?

Comment: Exactly what functionality is available in prettier that isn't available as well (even if in different form or with different rule settings) on eslint.